# Changing default value of cell using DJango and SQlite3

Tags: python, django

I have a problem, I am doing project in Django for my University, and I don't know how can I change value of cell in Database using views.py. My application is an application to do exams online and problem is that many users need to use it at the same time, so I need to do relations in database, like every question has an answer and that answer is provided by one user. And there is problem, I don't know how can I change this dynamically in Views.py. 
This is my code from Views.py:

```
 if form.is_valid():
    if username == Users.objects.latest('name'):
        Choice.objects.username = Users.objects.get('name')
```

And my models.py:

```
class Answers(models.Model):
question = models.ForeignKey(Questions, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
text = models.TextField()
def __str__(self):
    return self.text

class Users(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
pass = models.CharField(max_length=30)
def __str__(self):
    return self.name

class Choice(models.Model):
username = models.ForeignKey(Users, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
question = models.ForeignKey(Questions, null=True,  on_delete=models.CASCADE)
answer = models.CharField(null=True,max_length=50)

class Questions(models.Model):
text = models.CharField(max_length=150)
madeBy = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=False, default='kacper', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
def __str__(self):
    return self.text
```

Also if you have any other idea how could I improve this would be great, it's first time that I'm doing something in DJango.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you want to update("how can I change value of cell ...") an specific object. To do this you can use following command :

```
YourModel.objects.filter(pk=yourobject_pk).update(username=Users.objects.get('name'))
```

Have this in mind, first you have to `filter` the object you want to update(I suggest doing this by id) and then `update` the field(cell) you want.

Comment: Thank you very much for help!